# Android Studio. NoClassDefFound Error for GooglePlayServiceUtil

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Newbie to android and android studio.. Trying to use Google Play Services for implementing GCM. Was following [how to set up play-services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.)

and 
     [Demo GCM Client](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java)

But got

```
01-01 21:01:25.094  11590-11590/com.abc.ads E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil
        at com.abc.ads.DummyActivity.checkPlayServices(DummyActivity.java:101).
```

There are answers for this same issue in SO itself. But all of them are "ecclipse" related. How solve this in Android Studio?

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio (i/O Preview) 0.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.0 or later, or clean and rebuild your project if you want to stay on 0.3.2. There's a bug in the 0.6 versions of the Gradle plugin (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63366) that can cause newly-added dependencies to not get linked into your APK unless you clean your project after doing so.